# java 1.7.0_21 - Duplicate extensions not allowed - OS/X

Tags: ssl-certificate, java-7

```
KeychainStore Ignored Exception: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed
```

I've written a desktop application in Java 7 to run on Windows and OS/X. Our users all have a special certificate installed on their computers, into the respective native keystores. There is a mac book user in Germany who receives the above error message when his client tries to access the KeychainStore. Has anyone seen anything like this? It works fine on my macbook and all of the Windows clients. Just his machine is having this problem, and I don't get it. I've verified his certificate is fine by having him visit a web service in his browser.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Just wondering if you found a solution for this problem. I'm having the same problem for couple days now. Also only on OSX (app work just fine on Windows).